Error when using WDS
I have configured WDS on my Windows server, installed Windows images and, when I try to install the system on another computer with Ubuntu already installed, I get the following errors as per the screenshot below:
PXE-T04: Illegal operation error.
PXE-E36: Error received from TFTP server
PXE-M0F: Exiting Intel PXE ROM.
Operating System not found


